# FileNotFoundException EACCES (Permission Denied)

Tags: android, file, exception, filenotfoundexception

I'm getting an exception that file open permission is denied when I'm trying to open a FileInputStream.

```
 File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
           .getAbsolutePath() + "/test/test.txt");
 try {
      FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(myFile); // crash
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
 System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/test/test.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
 System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
 System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)

 ...

 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
```

And yes, I do have the permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527767/open-failed-eacces-permission-denied)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android is case sensitive. Replace `ANDROID.PERMISSION` with `android.permission`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also, you should only need one of those permissions. If you are planning on writing to external storage, you should not also need `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: Right, thanks. AndroidStudio auto-completed it in all caps. Totally missed that.

Comment: @DavidM: "AndroidStudio auto-completed it in all caps" -- seriously? What version of Android Studio are you running? I'd like to see if I can reproduce it and, if I can, get a bug report filed for it. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I typed <uses-pe, hit enter to complete, then started typing EXTER to get it to go to external storage and just scrolled to it and let it complete. AndroidStudio 1.2.1.1, this machine running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @DavidM: That issue is already reported, as it turns out: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=173977

Comment: have the same problem, but this doesn't solve it :/ does anyone know what else can be the reason of exception?