# java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

I got this error when I trying to storage a bitmap into storage #

```
    File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "picture");
    if (! path.exists()) {
        path.mkdirs();
        if (!path.exists()) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss", Locale.CHINA).format(new Date());
    File imagePath = new File(path.getPath() + "_" + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    BufferedOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos =new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(imagePath));
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        return imagePath;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
```

`fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(imagePath));`

I debug and found this line cause the error.

And in manifest the permission set is right

Comment: what all permissions you have given?

Comment: "And in manifest the permission set is right" -- please post the manifest. Also, what version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.mount_unmount_filesystems" />
   the permission is out of <application>tag

Comment: minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 22

Comment: Maybe try imagePath.createFile() before open OutputStream ?

Comment: imagePath.createNewFile() get java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) and I didn't found method createFIle()

Comment: `ANDROID.PERMISSION` should also be `android.permission`.

Comment: I write both  <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />and
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />but I get FileNotFoundException in the same line

Comment: I remove the code: imagePath.createFile() ; it's can working but when the fos.close(); it throws an IOException e.

Answer (score 19):

This issue is in Android Pie and higher version.
So, adding this line in manifest file fixed error.

```
<application
    ...
    ...
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
</application>
```

Comment: This is a temporary fix or until Android 11 is out.

Answer (score 10):

**on Android10**

```
use method -> Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

---

Before your app is fully compatible with scoped storage, you can temporarily opt out based on your app's target SDK level or the requestLegacyExternalStorage manifest attribute:

Google has a new feature on Android Q: filtered view for external storage. A quick fix for that is to add this code in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

---

```
<manifest ... >
  <!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting
       Android 10 or higher. -->
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is my permission format was wrong

> Uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

The `android.permission` should be lowercase

> uses-permission
>   android:name=android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

and if I add `imagePath.createNewFile();`

it's also throws `FileNotFoundExceptions`.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problems. The Uppercase permissions were auto-generated by Android Studio