# FileNotFoundException:EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, file-permissions, fileoutputstream

I get data from my service :

```
        JSONObject userGuid = new JSONObject();
        userGuid.put("userGuid", id);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        String response = HttpUtil.post(mService + "GetUser", userGuid.toString(), mCookie);

        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response).getJSONObject("User");
        String temp = result.getJSONArray("UserImage").toString();
```

in received data, there is an **Base64** image user and I got it and convert it to **arryByte** and then I convert it to **InputStream** :

```
        byte[] tmp = Base64.decode(temp, Base64.DEFAULT);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(tmp);
```

I want to write it to a **File** by **outputStream** :

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

but I got this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/fcImages/581864034: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

In manifest I added these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

What is your Idea?

**Edit**
I create file in this way:

```
public class FileCache {

private File cacheDir;

public FileCache(Context context) {

    if((Environment
            .getExternalStorageState()).equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            cacheDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "fcImages");
    } else {
        cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    }
    if(!cacheDir.mkdirs()) {
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }
}

public File getFile(String id) {
    String filename = String.valueOf(id.hashCode());
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    return f;
}
```

Comment: witch Android OS Version  you test ??

Comment: I am using api 23

Comment: Probably you need to read this. You must ask for permission in your code before trying to "use" it :) . https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: the same code is correct in this api but only difference is the other project I used a uri to get images and then write it:`URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);`

Comment: Just check permissions of your application in your device settings. Android api 23 and newest are ignoring your manifest permissions. Now it requires user-interaction to allow it. Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: @grabarz121 I create this file in the recyclerView Adapter. is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 things that come in my mind to check:

1. uses-permission tag is inside manifest tag (and not application tag)
2. EACCESS may due to the fact that `fcImages` directory does not exist, or it is a file
3. permission for Android api 23 must be requested runtime

Source for (1) is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9907574/2319299), while source for (3) is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33288986/2319299)

Comment: uses permission is out side of my manifest: `<manifest ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Design">`

Comment: I don't understand if you solved your issue or not. I'm quite confident about the second reasons (a permission will throw a Permission Error)

Comment: I have a problem . I saw `fcImages` file is created

Comment: the same EACCESS is raised when you try to create a file inside another file. `fcImages` must be a directory

Comment: permission for Android api 23 must be requested runtime was correct.

Comment: Thank you. I will upvote andrei-terecoasa and grabarz121 comments, because it was their suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing the file to the application's internal storage. Try this:

Example 1:

```
java.io.File xmlFile = new java.io.File((getActivity()
      .getApplicationContext().getFileStreamPath("FileName.xml")
      .getPath()));
```

Also give the manifest permission correct way as below:

Example 2 :

```
<manifest>
        <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        ...
        <application>
            ...
            <activity> 
                ...
            </activity>
        </application>
 </manifest>
```