# File storage error when trying to display an OpenStreetMap map

Tags: java, android, sqlite, openstreetmap

My Android app using OpenStreetMap, which has been perfectly working for months, is now not able anymore to display the OpenStreetMap map. Despite the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission granted, I get messages like these :

```
E/OsmDroid: Unable to start the SQLite tile writer. Check external storage availability.
I/StorageUtils: /storage/emulated/0 is NOT writable
```

As I am targetting API29 and running on an Android 10 phone, I suppose the problem is related to the new policy about external storage access and the requirement to use the Storage Access Framework. Am I right?

No matter if I am right or wrong, does anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: Yes on Android Q that path is not writable. You should know that by now as your problem has been reported here five times a week for the last months.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57653808/588532

Comment: @Uriel Frankel, please dont advertise your hack as a fix. Your hack will not live long also.

Comment: @blackapps You are right

Comment: @blackapps but the official Android docs says: Running on Android 10
If your app targets Android 10 (API level 29), opt-out of scoped storage and continue using the approach for Android 9 and lower to perform this operation.

Comment: Yes, then lower target level.

Comment: Going back to API level 27 solved my problem (the logcat now tells me external storage is writable). Unfortunately, visually, it doesn't change anything : still no map but only the grid, the compass and the zoom buttons. In the logcat, I don't see any error or warning message, only `D/FA: Connected to remote service` which really looks like a good news, but don't know if it is related to OSM.

Comment: Better now I have changed the data source from `HIKEBIKEMAP` to `MAPNIK`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are targeting Andorid 10 - api 29, the official Android docs states:

> **Running on Android 10**
>
> If your app targets Android 10 (API level 29), opt-out of scoped
>   storage and continue using the approach for Android 9 and lower to
>   perform this operation.

So you need to add to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest ... >
<!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting
   Android 10 or higher. -->
    <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
     ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

@blackapps This is not a hack.

Comment: It is a hack that helps for a certain amount of time. A hack propagated by Google indeed. You better solve a problem right away.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to move the storage used for cache from external to internal. This must be done before the view is loaded/inflated.

For an Activity:

```
Configuration.getInstance().osmdroidTileCache = filesDir
```

For a fragment:

```
Configuration.getInstance().osmdroidTileCache = requireContext().filesDir
```

If using Activity binding, you must change the directory right before calling this:

```
binding = ActivityNameBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

Otherwise, the map view will be built and automatically attempt to access external storage.