# Unable to download Image from ImageView in Kotlin Causing App Crash

Tags: java, android, kotlin, imageview

```
button.setOnClickListener {

        saveToGallery()}
```

This is the button which is calling the `saveToGallery()` function

```
  private fun saveToGallery()
{

 val iv = findViewById<View>(R.id.photo_image) as ImageView
        val draw = iv.drawable

        val bitmap: Bitmap = draw.toBitmap()
        var outstream : FileOutputStream?=null
        val sdcard: File = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        val dir = File(sdcard.absolutePath + "/FlickrPics")
        dir.mkdirs()

        val filename:String = String.format("%d.png",System.currentTimeMillis())
        val outFile = File(dir,filename)
        try{
            outstream = FileOutputStream(outFile)
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()

        }
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,outstream)
        try {
            if (outstream != null) {
                outstream.flush()

            }

        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()

        }
        try {
            if (outstream != null) {
                outstream.close()
            }
        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

Comment: Pls, provide the crash stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem on this Line

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,outstream)
```

outstream is Null

if you put that in try catch then you see

```
System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException (No such file or directory)
```

Conclusion:

Your File is not created it require permission (In Manifest and Runtime also)

Add this two line in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Ask Permission Runtime

**Tested Code :**

```
private fun saveToGallery() {

    val draw = photo_image.drawable

    val bitmap: Bitmap = draw.toBitmap()
    var outstream: FileOutputStream? = null
    val sdcard: File = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    val dir = File(sdcard.absolutePath + "/FlickrPics")

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        Log.e("TAG", "is Dir Exist " + dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs()
    } else {
        Log.e("TAG", "is Dir Exist " + dir.exists())
    }

    val filename: String = String.format("%d.png", System.currentTimeMillis())
    val outFile = File(dir, filename)
    try {
        outstream = FileOutputStream(outFile)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()

    }
    try {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outstream)
    }catch (e: Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    try {
        outstream?.flush()

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()

    }
    try {
        outstream?.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask permission runtime or for now just give permission from setting (Storage),lemme know it work or not

Comment: I have given storage permission from settings still not working

Comment: I have updated my answer !! i edited your code and it is working!!

Comment: Thankyou,I'll check it out

Comment: please accept the answer if it will works for you

Comment: App doesn't crash but this error is showing

Comment: W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)

Comment: W stands for Warning not Error . And if you want to solve this warning then you have ask another question

Comment: If you got the image in File manager then this question is complete

Comment: I can't see the image anywhere after pressing download button

Comment: There's another error E/GraphicExt: GraphicExtModuleLoader::CreateGraphicExtInstance false can this be the reason for not downloading?

Comment: Do u have Folder "FlickrPics" in Internal Storage??

Comment: No I thought val dir = File(sdcard.absolutePath + "/FlickrPics") would create a new directory in storage

Comment: Are you getting message from this Log.e("TAG", "is Dir Exist " + dir.exists()) ??

Comment: I changes "/FlickrPics" to "Download" it is now showing as dir exist true

Comment: and you have your Image in Download Folder?

Comment: No,the image doesnt get downloaded it shows java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/1608125008608.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: You have give permission Runtime . 
Do u allowed the Storage permission from Setting of Phone?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527767/open-failed-eacces-permission-denied Second answer will help you

Comment: yes thankyou it worked you just have to enable permission storage using ContextCompat

Answer (score 0):

```
  private fun setupPermissions() {

        val permission =
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        val permissionRead = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permissionRead != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Permission to Write Storage denied")
            Log.d("TAG","Permission to Read Storage denied")
            makeRequest()
        }
    }
        private fun makeRequest() {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            ,WRITE_REQUEST_CODE)
        }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        when(requestCode){
            WRITE_REQUEST_CODE,READ_REQUEST_CODE -> {
                if(grantResults.isEmpty() || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    Log.i("TAG","Permission denied")
                }
                else {
                    Log.i("TAG","Permission granted")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Unless you request for permissions explicitly it won't work, these are the codes for requesting permissions,just call setupPermissions()in main activity