# Firebase Phone Authentication in Android Q

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Now that **Android Q** has a lot of behavioral changes in storage and data access of a file. My application can no longer be able to do these stuffs hence keeps my application crashing with multiple errors. As soon as a user clicks a button to receive a verification code the app crashes. The log file shows that it failed to make a directory in the internal storage. Hence `mkdir` failed to be executed.

```
W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure /data/user/0/com.fole_Studios.sup/databases: mkdir failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Hence, leads to the follwing error:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 38094 of [68b898381a]
    (14) os_unix.c:38094: (13) lstat(/data/user/0/com.fole_Studios.sup/databases/firestore.%5BDEFAULT%5D.supp-3924e.%28default%29) - 
    (1) Process ole_Studios.sup : Pid (836) Uid (10361) Euid (10361) Gid (10361) Egid (10361)
E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.fole_Studios.sup/databases/firestore.%5BDEFAULT%5D.supp-3924e.%28default%29'.
```

I referred to multiple answers in **Stack overflow** but non helped.
Most of the questions end up with the use of **Legacy storage** in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

I did the same but no success at all.

**Edited**

Another error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (22.0.0).
```

The error shows that it is caused by the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 1806 SQLITE_CANTOPEN_EACCES[1806]): Could not open database
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java:325)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source:4)
```

Also,

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 1806 SQLITE_CANTOPEN_EACCES[1806]): Could not open database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:300)
```

It seems the error occurs whenever I try to access the **firestore database**. I have tried to access different data from firestore but my app keeps on crashing.

The code below leads to the above errors:

```
_firestore.collection(USERS).whereEqualTo("phone_number", _phoneCheck).get();
```

Comment: What is the code the produces that error?

Comment: @AlexMamo, I have edited the question added more information and the code which causes the error. I have tried also to access the firestore database but seems I cannot and produces the same error above.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right permissions in your Android Manifest file?

Comment: Yes, I am. I have added both read and write to external storage. Also I have included to use legacy external storage.

Comment: This answer solved my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33288986/9942927